# Accessing an element in an xml file in php

Tags: php, xml, web

I am currently trying to access an element in an xml code. This is what my code looks like:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://www.transltr.org/api/getlanguagesfortranslate") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$languages = $xml -> ArrayOfLangauge[0];

print_r($languages);
```

The xml file is this

```
[
  {
    "languageCode": "ar",
    "languageName": "Arabic"
  },
  {
    "languageCode": "bs",
    "languageName": "Bosnian"
  },
  {
    "languageCode": "bg",
    "languageName": "Bulgarian"
  },
  {
    "languageCode": "ca",
    "languageName": "Catalan"
  },
  {
```

And so on...

Please help, I am new to this.

Comment: That is a json, not a xml. but the data of address does is a xml.

Comment: @LeonKrugliakov, just as Pablo has already mentioned, the output is not XML, it is JSON. Even the output you posted in your question is JSON. If you try my answer below, you will see that you can easily target any index, object or property. Check out [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_xml.asp) to learn the difference between XML and JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the API correctly from transltr.org. I whipped up something real quick based on the API documentation located here:
http://www.transltr.org/Developers

```
$url='http://www.transltr.org/api/getlanguagesfortranslate';
//Initiate curl
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
//Execute curl
$result=curl_exec($ch);
//Close curl
curl_close($ch);
//JSON decode the data from transltr.org
$languages=json_decode($result);
//Example of setting a variable to a single index
$show_english=$languages[10];
//Neatly print the singled out variable
printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($show_english,1));
//Just neatly print everything returned from the API
printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($languages,1));
```

I'm not sure exactly from your question what element you are trying to access, but I included an example of setting a variable to only one index (element) of the object. If you want to select a property of the object you could do something like this:

```
printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($show_english->languageName,1));
```

I hope that helps.